# fileUpload in asp.net MVC3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I want to use fileUpload in my MVC view which is an .aspx page.
I want to fetch the path into an object in my Controller.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("AddClient","Client",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype ="multipart/form-data" }))
   { %>
<div class="float-left">
<%: Html.Label("BAAFile Path") %>
<br />
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BAAFilePath) %>--%>
</div>
<% } %>
```

at the bottom of the page there is a button to Save details(no button beside fileupload control).

Now i want to fetch the path of fileupload control in to my controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ButtonName(Name = "Save")]
    public ActionResult AddClient(ClientService.ClientDto client,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                // extract only the fielname
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            }
    }
```

now i want to fetch the filepath

```
     var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
```

into object of "ClientService.ClientDto" which is "client".

```
     client.BAAFilePath=fileName
```

but iam getting null data into "var fileName".

iam using following code in "ActionResult AddClient(ClientService.ClientDto client)"

```
if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        // extract only the fielname
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

    }
```

am i missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest binding your form to a view model and then your view model to DTO.
Your view model should have a property "File" of type HttppostedFileBase, you'll then get everything bound properly when posting your form.
Make sure your form has the enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: i have edited my code. added ectype and HttppostedFileBase.still no change.Iam getting null only

Comment: when i use masterpage,its not working,if a take .aspx without masterpage its working fine.found that its because of "<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>" in master page.any help ?

Comment: how can i get filepath from "HttppostedFileBase file".I am getting filename.I want full path.

Comment: Why do you need the file path? Save wherever you want with the input stream or the SaveAs()